# Is there a way to prevent forecasting negative values in SPSS?

Tags: time-series, spss

Currently I'm using the SPSS expert modeler, the training series is a seasonal time series, with some values close to zero in each period, and I find that when the training series have a descending trend, then in the result of the forecast, there will be some negative values.

But the time series should be positive on every timestamps, is there a way to prevent forecasting negative values?

Comment: I think this is a general (not just SPSS related) question how to constrain time series forecasts not to produce negative values for observed values close to zero. And whether one should be bothered at all.

Comment: Working on a logarithmic scale and back-transforming would be a way of avoiding negative (and indeed zero) predictions. Whether it's a good idea for your project is an open question.